# Wordcount example hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop and trying to explore it via examples available on their website.So this might sound like a very basic question.

In Eclipse IDE I simply created a java project ,imported necessary hadoop jars and the core jar. I then ran a `WordCount` example that comes with downloadable and it ran successfully.

However, I didn't setup any Hadoop installation or a single node cluster.

Hence I am unable to figure out how can that job run even without hadoop being configured in my system.

My initial understanding was I will need to install hadoop following something like [Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) to get going, but apparently that was not necessary. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens in the scenario where the job only detects the local file system, where it uses the [LocalFileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/LocalFileSystem.html) API to interact with the files in the local file system.

Please refer the below link,
[Unit testing hadoop hdfs writings with MiniDFSCluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816565/unit-testing-hadoop-hdfs-writings-with-minidfscluster)

This is one of the option to Unit Test the mapreduce/hdfs code that we develop in the dev environment.While you deploy the same code in the hadoop clsuter , the input files will be expected in the HDFS location.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you run an internal test or something like that (the hadoop configuration can be generated in memory for testing purposes). You should install a single-node cluster and start doing real things, like that one in the guide that you previously referenced. Remember to check oficial hadoop site also.